# How to access my drupal site as https instead of http?

Tags: drupal, ssl, drupal-6, https

I am accessing my drupal site using http://localhost/drupal and I want to access it using https://localhost/drupal.
Any tutorial to follow???
I know that it will be done using secure login module of drupal and ssl but how would I use it?
I am using xampp server.
Please tell me about a tutorial on this so that I follow that tutorial and my work done.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy using xampp:

1. make sure extra/httpd-ssl.conf is loaded in apache/httpd.conf (under main directory of your xampp installation)
2. in httpd-ssl.conf: edit default or add new vhost, what you need is:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
       DocumentRoot "PATH_TO_DRUPAL_DIR"
       ServerName BOUND_DOMAIN_EG_LOCALHOST

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
       SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key

       <IfModule setenvif_module>
           BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
       </IfModule>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Update `base_url` in settings.php (if needed, looking at your drupal path, i think so)